# How to change the setting of WinEdt to open all newly generated PDF files in another PDF reader?

Tags: pdf, viewers, winedt

I am using WinEdt 6.0 software for my regular latex typesetting. The operating system is windows 8. There are several PDF viewers in my computer. Default PDF viewer is Foxit Reader. So a newly generated PDF file is always opened in Foxit. Uninstalling Foxit software I have seen that the WinEdt can not able to give me the PDF file.

I want to open all my newly generated PDF files by Adobe Reader whereas Foxit will act as my default PDF viewer. How to change the settings of WinEdt to do it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

main Menu

```
Options
  Execution mode
    PDF viewer
```

Now you can change the default PDF viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Not sure whether something has changed since WinEdt 6. I don't think it's very different in WinEdt 8, so I explain for the latter.

Open the `Execution Modes`interface from the `Options` menu and click on the `PDF Viewer` tab. There you will be able to choose the main pdf viewer and up to 4 alternative viewers, and also set the synctex parameter (for `forward and inverse search`).

[image]

Maybe you have good reasons to use Adobe Reader, but be aware that it locks .pdf files and, as far as I know, doesn't support the direct/inverse search feature that is allowed by `synctex`. That's why the recommended viewer is SumatraPDF, that has the advantage of being lightweight and very fast to load.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about the PDF viewer. I have no idea about SumatraPDF. I shall try with it.

Comment: I must say I use it as the default viewer for all .pdf files. The only reason why I also have Adobe Reader is SumatraPDF doesn't (yet) support forms. Btw you should upgrade to the latest version WinEdt: it now is a fully UTF8 editor, is faster and has code-folding, among other new features.